# How to use touchSwipe event to a sliding div in JQM website

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, jquery-mobile, swipe-gesture

I have a simple slider that works on click event . Then I am trying to add the same effect on sipe left right . But I am having trouble to do it

Here is the [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/YcW2V/4/) that I created .

I am using swipeTouch plugin for the gestures .

If some one can update the fiddle to do the same effect using swipe gestures would be really helpful .

**Script**

```
$(".fieldset").swipe({
    swipe: function (event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
        // $(this).text("You swiped " + direction );

        if (direction == 'right') {
            console.log("You swiped " + direction);
        }
    }
});

$('ul li.fieldset').each(function () {
    var h = $(this).height();
    var next_height = $(this).next('.hidenset').height();
    var diff = h - next_height;
    console.log('The height of li:' + h);
    $(this).next('.hidenset').css('height', h + 'px');
    $(this).next('.hidenset').css('margin-top', -h + 'px');

});

$(".fieldset a").click(function () {
    parent = $(this).parent('.fieldset');
    $('.fieldset').not(parent).removeClass('left-slide').addClass('right-slide');

    if ($(parent).hasClass('left-slide')) {
        $(parent).removeClass('left-slide').addClass('right-slide');
    } else {
        $(parent).removeClass('right-slide').addClass('left-slide');
    }

    form = $(parent).attr('id');
    var arr = form.split('_');
    var menu = '#menu_' + arr[1];

    $('.hidenset').not(menu).removeClass('menu-open').addClass('menu-close');

    if ($(menu).hasClass('menu-open')) {
        $(menu).removeClass('menu-open').addClass('menu-close');
    } else {
        $(menu).removeClass('menu-close').addClass('menu-open');
    }

});
```

Thanks & regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

> Updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/YcW2V/6/)**

```
$(".fieldset").swipe({
  swipe:function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
   // $(this).text("You swiped " + direction );
   alert("You swiped " + direction );
   if(direction == 'right') {
       //only slide if menu is open
       if($(this).hasClass('left-slide')) {
           $(this).find("#sub2").click();
       }
   } else if (direction == 'left') {
       //only slide if menu is closed
       if($(this).hasClass('right-slide')) {
           $(this).find("#sub2").click();
       }
   }
  }
});
```

You check the direction of the swipe and see if the menu is already in the appropriate state. If not, find the button in the fieldset and trigger the click event.

Comment: just one comment on this . Yesterday while using the swipe event I found out that . If I use `swipe:function()` then it effects the other touch events of `jqueryMobile` . SO for that we should only use the events that are requeired in my case `swiperight:function()` and `swipeleft:function()` . :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on answer provided by @ezanker

My answer goes for those who try to  use [**Jquery Mobile**](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.3/) + [**TouchSwipe**](http://labs.rampinteractive.co.uk/touchSwipe/demos/) .

If we use just the `swipe:function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {}` function then it effects the other `touch`  events of JQM is being effected since it is a touch optimized version of `JQuery`.

**Script**

```
$(".fieldset").swipe({
                  swipeLeft: function (event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
            //only slide if menu is open
                if ($(this).hasClass('right-slide')) {

                $(this).find(".anchor1").click();
            }
        },
     swipeRight: function (event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
            //only slide if menu is closed
            if ($(this).hasClass('left-slide')) {
                $(this).find(".anchor1").click();
            }
        }
});
```

I used touchSwipe because `swipeleft` and `swiperight` events of **JQM** was not responding properly in browsers

Hope it helps to some one